# Ember doesn't allow bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have problem with [daterange picker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) and Ember.

On Ember1.10. `index.html` page on bottom i put

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
 </script>
```

that works for me, until in random route where i use datarange define model

```
App.RandomRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
   model:function(){
     return this.store.find('user');
   }})
```

Problem is when i return some value in model function,

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 1:30 PM - 01/01/2015 2:00 PM" />
```

html render this input like normal input type text,don't allow calendar pop-up

Comment: Youll probably need a newer version of ember but someone has made an add on of this for ember https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-cli-daterangepicker

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, the code that converts the input to a datetimepicker is only run once.

**EDIT**

The following answer applies [Ember 1.13 and newer versions](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks).

Create a component to wrap datepicker. Put this code to your component's `didInsertElement` or `didRender` hook.

Such as:

```
didInsertElement:function(){
  Ember.$().datetimepicker();
}
```

Ref: [from guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code).

Thanks to kumkanillam, to correcting the wrong name of the hook.

Comment: You mean didRender hook.

Comment: @kumkanillam even in ember.js 2.x didInsertElement works just fine. And official guide [suggests to use it](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code) for integration with jquery plugins

Comment: It was my mistake, instead of `didRender`, I had written `afterRender`.